# change filtred class of ng-repeat by $index from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my ng-repeat:

```
<div class="{{event.who_seen_it | newEvent}}" ng-repeat="event in eventList" ng-click="openEvet(event.title,$index)">
    <h3 class="event-title">{{event.title}}</h3>
</div>
```

I use `{{event.who_seen_it | newEvent}}` for adding class to each repeated element. I want to changing result of this filter `newEvent` or adding new class to current element or remove this filter `{{event.who_seen_it | newEvent}}` by click on each repeated element.

We can use the `$index` and I want to do it from the controller. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what does `event.who_seen_it` contain and give the code for the `newEvent` filter ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add/remove classes is with `ng-class`. You can define a map of `key:value` where the `key` is a class and `value` is a condition which, when evaluated to some thruthy value, the associated class is added to the element. For instance, assuming the `visited` class is defined:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="event in ctrl.eventList track by $index" 
      ng-class="{'visited':event.visited}"
      ng-click="event.visited = true">{{event.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

When an *event* is clicked, the `visited` property is set to `true`, then the `visited` class is added to the `<li>` element.

`ng-class` takes a object/map and you can have multiple key/value defined, with different conditions. [See plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YY4IzDN5Ju6pnTorCJmQ?p=preview)

See [ng-class documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) because there are other ways to use it.